# Lag in ScrollViewDidScroll when using it to dynamically resize a UIStackView item

Tags: iphone, uiscrollview, autolayout, lag, uistackview

Before I begin, please don't shoot the messenger - this is functionality required by the client, so discussions as to the higher-level rights and wrongs of UX in this instance probably aren't going to help very much.

Anyway, my dilemma is as follows. I have a vertical UIStackView containing a number of items, each with their own collection of subviews.

The top item in this vertical UIStackView contains a horizontal paged UIScrollView on which is added a horizontal UIStackView containing a number of items of different heights.

Now because the horizontal UIStackView contains items of different heights, when its containing UIScrollView scrolls left and right, thereby bringing new items onto the screen (and sliding previous items off) the height NSLayoutConstraint of the UIStackView and parent UIScrollView needs to change to accomodate. This ensures that all of the vertical UIStackView items beneath this top item slide down out of the way (and back up) where needed, all automatically.

This dynamic resizing is all being done within scrollViewDidScroll of the top item's UIScrollView.

And believe it or not this does actually all work, with just one problem: when a resize is required I get UIScrollView lag. If no resizing is required, I don't.

Now from the evidence it would seem autolayout, UIStackViews, and scrollViewDidScroll are not playing well together when the resizing is taking place, I am also under the impression that this is related to the vertical UIStackView calling layoutSubviews on all of its children for every frame of scrollViewDidScroll that actually changes the height of the top item. If I remove all UIStackView items except for the top item containing the UIScrollView + horizontal UIStackView, scrolling is seamless when resizing. In addition, if I put the resize into an animation block within scrollViewDidScroll which is called once, it is again seamless.

So the question is, has anyone come across anything similar in the past and found a way around it? Is there anything I'm missing? Does anyone know if UIStackView layoutSubviews calls can be somehow prevented or blocked in this instance? Thoughts would be very welcome as removing the use of autolayout and UIStackViews would likely have somewhat large and expensive ramifications.

Comment: please share some code @Afox